PLAID: Removing an item and reactivating it again
I'm using plaid in a project where I will be billing my customers.
But if there is no payment (account deactivation or billing unsubscribed) then I need to remove the item so I dont keep getting charged for it.
For this case scenario, how do I approach the case where a customer decides to resubscribe and pick up where he left of?
The items would be invalid if I did an item/remove when the subscription ended but I dont see a way to reenable them.
I dont want to have the client to reconnect his accounts again and resync all the data.
Thanks in advance

There is no way to do this; the end user will need to re-connect their account.
Also note that storing financial / payment data belonging to a user of your service after they have deactivated their account or subscription billing is not a recommended practice for data minimization reasons; you may also be legally required not to retain this information. (You should determine what regulations and legal considerations apply to your scenario.)
